# Looking for an explanation on the results of identity testing on integer variables in Python

Tags: python, boolean, logic, operators, identity

I have a simple code I stumbled upon on HyperSkill and was testing it on the Python console, both Python2 and Python3. The results confused me.

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 5
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
True
>>> x = 1000
>>> y = 1000
>>> x == y
True
>>> x is y
False
>>>
```

I don't understand why the result of `a is b` is `True` and yet the result of `x is y` is (as expected) `False`

Comment: @DeepSpace Another answer worth examining:  [Is there a difference between “==” and “is”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)

Comment: Or this.. [“is” operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)
@DeepSpace, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `is` operator compares whether two objects are assigned to the same underlying object in memory.  The `==` operator compares whether two objects have the equivalent value.

Small integer values (-5 to 256) are stored in memory in Python for efficiency.  Assigning a variable to be one of those value integers will always assign it to the **same** underlying object in Python's memory.  For larger values, a new object is created.

Here is some code to show it:

```
for x, y in zip(range(-7,260), range(-7,260)):
    print(x, x is y)

# prints:
-7 False
-6 False
-5 True
-4 True
-3 True
-2 True
-1 True
0 True
1 True
2 True
... 
254 True
255 True
256 True
257 False
258 False
259 False
```

Comment: `"(0 to 255 or -128 to 127, I forget which)"` Neither. -5 to 256 (in the current CPython implementation)

Comment: Thank you!  I could not find it in the documentation.

Comment: It's an implementation detail of CPython. See https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong